# Scale a Series Using a Specific Value as Our Baseline

Tags: r, scale, normalize

Example series:

`test <- data.frame(value = c(71,90,23,40,41), day = c(1,2,3,4,5))`

Let's say I wanted to scale this short series normalized to 100, using the first value "71" as our baseline. If plotted then our first value is at 100 on the y-axis, and everything following is scaled accordingly. For example, the following value in the series "90" would plot above 100 on the y-axis.

I've used the normalize function from the BBmisc package, setting the range parameters to min (1) and max (100):

`test$value <- normalize(test$value, method = "range", range = c(1,100))`

Which does scale appropriately between 1 and 100, but plotting yields the maximum value "90" at 100 on the y-axis. I have also tried this:

`test$value <- normalize(test$value, method = "range", range = c(test$value[3], test$value[1]))`

But this just slightly rescales the initial values around these min and max values.

Comment: I think you have to scale manually.  `test$value2 <- (test$value / 71) * 100`

Comment: Ha, great, this is perfect. Much simpler than I was thinking. Thank you!

Comment: Great, please uptick my comment.